# aws cognito phone number regex validation faild

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, phone-number

when creating a user from aws via the console. they used below regex validation pattern as per below screenshot.

regex pattern

```
"^\+[1-9][0-9]{0,24}$"
```

but when i try this mobile number with python it was matched. but in the console or api it gives an error called invalid mobile number

sample mobile number +80570497

[image: cognito user creation]

python script

```
>>> re.match(r"^\+[1-9][0-9]{0,24}$", "+80570497")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='+80570497'>
>>>
```

Comment: Do you have any leading  or trailing whitespace?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM nop. i verified.

Comment: I think phone number also have to 10 digits right?

Comment: Note the error message: *"Phone number must fit ... **and be a valid phone number**"* - presumably there are some validations that render that input invalid regardless of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito said:

> Enter the user's phone number, **including country code**. The phone number is not a required attribute based on your selections and user pool configuration.

You are missing the country code in your phone number you have to follow the [**E.164 format**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164). For example, if this is a Sri Lanka phone number, it should be written as *+9480570497*, where `94` is the country calling code for Sri Lanka.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito seems to be doing some more validation besides the regex from the screenshot. For example numbers starting with +80,+21,+259 and more.
Looks like it does not allow any country codes that's are currently unassigned from this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes